# problemas mapper no puede mapear alguna propiedad

Tags: java

Estas son lasl entidades y dto

```
 CitaDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6L;
    private Integer id;
    private Date fHoraCita;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "listaCitas", "listaInformes" })
    private PacienteDTO paciente;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("listaCitas")
    private MedicoDTO medico;
```

hospital

```
 HospitalDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7L;
    private String nombreHos;
    private String poblacion;
    private String numConsultas;
    private List<MedicoDTO> listaMedicos;
```

InformeCompletoDTO

```
public class InformeCompletoDTO {

    private String url;
    private String nombreInf;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "paciente", "medico" })
    private MedicoDTO medico;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "medico", "paciente" })
    private PacienteDTO paciente;
```

InformeDTO

```
InformeDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8L;
    protected String url;
    protected String nombreInf
```

InformeMedicoDTO

```
InformeMedicoDTO extends InformeDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "listaCitas", "informes" })
    private PacienteDTO paciente;
```

informePaciente

```
InformePacienteDTO extends InformeDTO {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"listaCitas", "informes"})
    private MedicoDTO medico;
```

medico

```
MedicoDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9L;
    private String nLicencia;
    private String nombre;
    private String especialidad;
    private int consulta;
    private String password;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("listaMedicos")
    private HospitalDTO hospital;
    private List<CitaDTO> listaCitas;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("listaMedicos")
    private List<InformeDTO> listaInformes;
```

Paciente

```
PacienteDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10L;
    private String nSS;
    private String nombre;
    private String password;
    private Date fNacimiento;
    private List<CitaDTO> citas;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("paciente")
    private List<InformeDTO> informes;
```

Cita

```
Cita implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "f_hora_cita")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fHoraCita;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nss", referencedColumnName = "nss")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "listaCitas", "listaInformes" })
    private Paciente paciente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "n_licencia", referencedColumnName = "n_licencia")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "listaCitas", "listaInformes" })
    private Medico medico;
```

Hospital

```
Hospital implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre_hos")
    private String nombreHos;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "poblacion")
    private String poblacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nomero_consultas")
    private String numConsultas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "hospital")
    private List<Medico> listaMedicos;
```

Informe

```
Informe implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre_inf")
    private String nombreInf;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "url", unique = true)
    private String url;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nss", referencedColumnName = "nss")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Paciente paciente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "n_licencia", referencedColumnName = "n_licencia")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Medico medico;


Medico implements Serializable, Logable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
    @Id
    @Size(max = 12)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "n_licencia")
    private String nLicencia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "especialidad")
    private String especialidad;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "consulta")
    private int consulta;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @JoinColumn(name = "nombre_hos")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("listaMedicos")
    private Hospital hospital;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medico")
    private List<Cita> listaCitas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medico")
    private List<Informe> listaInformes;
```

Paciente

```
Paciente implements Serializable, Logable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nss")
    private String nSS;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "f_nacimiento")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fNacimiento;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "paciente")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "paciente", "medico" })
    private List<Cita> listaCitas;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "paciente")
    private List<Informe> informes;
```

Este es uno de los errores

```
Unmapped target property: "listaCitas". Mapping from property "PacienteDTO listaMedicos[].listaCitas[].paciente" to "Paciente listaMedicos[].listaCitas[].paciente".
Hospital convertirAEntidadH(HospitalDTO dTO);

Unmapped target properties: "paciente, medico". Mapping from Collection element "InformeDTO medico.listaInformes" to "Informe medico.listaInformes".
Cita convertirAEntidadC(CitaDTO dTO);

Unmapped target property: "citas". Mapping from property "Paciente medico.listaCitas[].paciente" to "PacienteDTO medico.listaCitas[].paciente".
InformePacienteDTO convertirADTOIP(Informe entidad);

Unmapped target properties: "paciente, medico". Mapping from Collection element "InformeDTO listaInformes" to "Informe listaInformes".

Medico convertirAEntidadM(MedicoDTO dTO);
```

No consigo solucionar el problema tengo mapstruct

Comment: Pues eso. InformeDTO tienen menos columnas que Informe y estás indicando en la anotación Column que mapee columnas que no declaras. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: pero es que efectivamente no puede contener lo mismo. ademas con modelmapper si funciona es mapstruck el que da error